# How to migrate to translatable fields

Tags: i18n-l10n, migrations

I am using the latest [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module in order to provide a couple of translatable fields for some of my content types. I have a content type which has a translatable field which is called "title_field".

I am using the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module (version 2.0) in order to fill in the Drupal scheme with data from an old database. Normally, in a single language, the line would be:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('title_field','name')
```

Now the problem is that I have two translations of this field in my old database, which I want to create through the migration API.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('title_field','name_el')->arguments(array('language','el'));
$this->addFieldMapping('title_field','name_en')->arguments(array('language','en'));
```

Unfortunately this last one does not work. Any idea how I can go further with this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by first doing the field translation manually for one node, and then using Node Export to see the actual code describing the node.
Finally, I used the prepare function of the Migrate api to do the work manually.

```
function prepare($entity, stdClass $row){

    $entity->language = 'el';       
    $entity->title_field['el'][0]['value'] = $row->name;
    $entity->title_field['en'][0]['value'] = $row->name_en;
    $entity->translations = (object) array(
                    'original' => 'el',
                    'data' => array(
                            'el' => array(
                                    'entity_type' => 'node',
                                    'entity_id' => $entity->nid,
                                    'language' => 'el',
                                    'source' => '',
                                    'uid' => '0',
                                    'status' => '1',
                                    'translate' => '0',

                            ),
                            'en' => array(
                                    'entity_type' => 'node',
                                    'entity_id' => $entity->nid,
                                    'language' => 'en',
                                    'source' => 'el',
                                    'uid' => '1',
                                    'status' => '1',
                                    'translate' => '0',

                            ),
                    )
            );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

lefterav solution has a problem: in `prepare()` function, `$entity` is not yet saved, so `$entity->nid` is not set.

To solve this problem, I used `complete()` function:

```
public function complete($entity, stdClass $row) {
$entity->translations = (object) array(
  'original' => 'it',
  'data' => array(
    'it' => array(
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'entity_id' => $entity->nid,
      'language' => 'it',
      'source' => '',
      'uid' => '1',
      'status' => '1',
      'translate' => '0',
    ),
    'en' => array(
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'entity_id' => $entity->nid,
      'language' => 'en',
      'source' => 'it',
      'uid' => '1',
      'status' => '1',
      'translate' => '0',
    ),
  )
);
entity_save('node', $entity);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Import data in multiple languages](https://www.drupal.org/node/907542)

> This tutorial will explain, step-by-step, how to import multilingual
>   data into Drupal. This is important for projects that require data to
>   be imported, whether it's new data, data from an old site, or even
>   from a desktop application.